# Storing a nested dictionary of tuples in python

Tags: python, json, dictionary, tuples, pickle

I have a dictionary of dictionaries that uses tuples as it's keys and values. I would like to write this dictionary and have tried json and pickle but neither of them seem to work. Is there a better alternative?

https://github.com/jgv7/markov-generator/blob/master/sentence-generator.py

Comment: When you say "neither of them seem to work", can you describe what problems you've seen, exactly?

Comment: JSON and `pickle` are very popular modules that work fine as long as you use them properly. If they "don't work," the problem lies elsewhere.

Comment: Include your code in the question; don't just link to code. And _especially_ not to code that's going to change the next time there's a commit (as it's just pointing to `master`).

Comment: Instead of a link to your full code, please include a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) in your question that reproduces the problem you're having.

Answer (score 1):

json expects the key of the Key value pair to be a string or a number that can be properly converted to a string. bottom line - cant do a json.dumps on a dict with tuples as keys.

pickle should work unless the dictionary object is not properly serialized.

Comment: Thanks educating me! As BlackJack pointed out I was also using pickle incorrectly so the issue is now fixed.

Comment: glad it worked out for you. It seemed like you were getting an Exception thrown at. my bad assuming that. cheers!!

Answer (score 0):

From your code:

```
with open(filename, 'rb') as df:
    pickle.load(df)
print mapping
```

You don't bind the result of the `load()` call to a name, so that line has no effect (other than consuming processor time and moving the file pointer).  That should read:

```
with open(filename, 'rb') as df:
    mapping = pickle.load(df)
print mapping
```

Comment: Thanks, BlackJack! This is exactly the issue. This was my first time using pickle and of course the example code I used was in error.